# jQuery: How to properly pause a recursion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, settimeout

I know there are a lot of questions on the topic, but it seems none of the answers works for me (or maybe I don't see something obvious). I am building a featured content slider that should pause on hover. However, if I move over with the mouse 5-6 times, it goes through the loop 5-6 times at once and it becomes buggy. The previous recursion doesn't stop and a new one is initiated too.

My function:

```
gravityFeatured.prototype.loop = function(slide) {

    // Begin
    var self = this;
    if(typeof slide == 'undefined') {
        slide = 0;
    }
    self.slidesWrapper.find('.slide-wrapper').removeClass('current next prev');
    self.navigation.find('.navigation-item').removeClass('current');

    // Current slide
    currentSlide = self.slidesWrapper.find('.slide-wrapper[data-slide="' + slide + '"]');
    currentNav = self.navigation.find('.navigation-item[data-slide="' + slide + '"]');

    // Next slide
    var nextSlide = self.slidesWrapper.find('.slide-wrapper[data-slide="' + (slide + 1) + '"]');
    var next = slide+1;
    if(!nextSlide.length) {
        nextSlide = self.slidesWrapper.find('.slide-wrapper[data-slide="0"]');
        next = 0;
    }

    // Prev slide
    var prevSlide = self.slidesWrapper.find('.slide-wrapper[data-slide="' + (slide - 1) + '"]');
    if(!prevSlide.length) {     
        prevSlide = self.slidesWrapper.find('.slide-wrapper[data-slide="' + (self.slides.length - 1) + '"]');
    }

    // Assign classes
    currentSlide.addClass('current');
    currentNav.addClass('current');
    nextSlide.addClass('next');
    prevSlide.addClass('prev');

    self.scrollNavigation(slide);

    // Loop
    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        self.loop(next);
    }, self.options['delay']);

    self.slidesWrapper.hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){self.loop(next);});
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Yeah, it cancels everything and when I move the mouse out the function doesn't continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the current setup every time you mouseout you trigger a move. Thus in and out 5 times is going to trigger 5 moves. Perhaps better behavious is to pause the countdown while the mouse is in the hovering. This would look something like:

```
gravityFeatured.countdown = null,
gravityFeatured.isPaused = false,
gravityFeatured.prototype.loop = function(slide) {
...
    self.scrollNavigation(slide);

    self.countdown = self.options['delay'] * 1000;

    var timeout = null; /* need this in loopCheck */
    var loopCheck = function() {
        if (!this.isPaused)
            this.countdown -= 500;

        if (this.countdown <= 0)
            this.loop(next);
        else
            timeout = setTimeout(loopCheck,500); /* check every half sec */
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(loopCheck,500);

    self.slidesWrapper.hover(function(){
         self.isPaused = true
    }, function(){
         self.isPaused = false;
    });
}
```

A half second timeout might be a little long, could probably go down to 250ms if necessary. Should handle lots of mouse movement okay though.

Comment: One question, when I set the countdown to 250, the delay between slides seems to slow down. Not that I will need 250, just curious why this happens.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to put 250 in the last call `timeout = setTimeout(loopCheck,250);`, my bad. :)